# WP query for two post types how to order newest to oldest with two different meta fields?

Tags: wp-query

I am doing a simple WP query that gets posts: ('post', 'event').

the events I needed ordered by a custom date field: start_date'

the posts I need ordered by date.

I need the two output together in order.

I read: [Query two post types and order by two different date fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278005/query-two-post-types-and-order-by-two-different-date-fields)

The guys sounds like he did some work with js.  I need this to be a paginate-able query.  There are 100+ posts and probably 12-14 events.

TIA

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be possible using WP_Query. It can be done with custom SQL query, but it won't be very pretty solution, I guess... Maybe you should change the info structure/storage method...

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of.